# What is exactly happening in Linux page table pointers dereferencing?

Tags: linux, assembly, linux-kernel, page-tables

I’m trying to investigate page table walk in Linux kernel. I used standard way to walk through page table to find PFN (just for example, not actual code):

```
    pgd_t *pgd; pte_t *ptep; pte_t pte; pud_t *pud; pmd_t *pmd;
    struct page *pagePtr = NULL;
    struct mm_struct *mm = current->mm;
    pgd = pgd_offset(mm, addr);
    pud = getPud(pgd, addr);
    pmd = pmd_offset(pud, addr);
    ptep = pte_offset_map(pmd, addr);
    size_t pfn = pte_pfn(pte);
```

The system is

> CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770
>
> CPU @ 3.40GHz
>
> OS: Linux Fedora release 22 (Twenty Two) Kernel: 4.4.4-200.fc22.x86_64

I’m trying to understand how pgd pointer dereferenced to pud pointer. I put simple code into getPud function:

```
noinline pud_t *getPud(pgd_t *pgdPtr, unsigned long addr).
{
    return pud_offset(pgdPtr, addr);
}
```

And try to disassemble it by objdump

```
00000000000000b0 <getPud>:
  b0:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  b5 <getPud+0x5>
  b5:   55                      push   %rbp
  b6:   48 8b 3f                mov    (%rdi),%rdi
  b9:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  bc:   ff 14 25 00 00 00 00    callq  *0x0
  c3:   48 c1 ee 1b             shr    $0x1b,%rsi
  c7:   48 ba 00 00 00 00 00    movabs $0xffff880000000000,%rdx
  ce:   88 ff ff
  d1:   81 e6 f8 0f 00 00       and    $0xff8,%esi
  d7:   48 01 d6                add    %rdx,%rsi
  da:   48 ba 00 f0 ff ff ff    movabs $0x3ffffffff000,%rdx
  e1:   3f 00 00
  e4:   48 21 d0                and    %rdx,%rax
  e7:   48 01 f0                add    %rsi,%rax
  ea:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  eb:   c3                      retq
  ec:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
```

My assembler knowledge is not enough to understand constructions like `callq  *0x0`

Could someone please shed some light on what is going on in getPud?

Thank you

Sergey

**Update 1**

I used objdump to disassemble LKM (cpes.ko) module I created to walk through page table.

```
>objdump -dr ./cpes.ko

./cpes.ko:     file format elf64-x86-64
Disassembly of section .text:
00000000000000b0 <getPud>:
  b0:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  b5 <getPud+0x5>
                        b1: R_X86_64_PC32       __fentry__-0x4
  b5:   55                      push   %rbp
  b6:   48 8b 3f                mov    (%rdi),%rdi
  b9:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  bc:   ff 14 25 00 00 00 00    callq  *0x0
                        bf: R_X86_64_32S        pv_mmu_ops+0xf8
  c3:   48 c1 ee 1b             shr    $0x1b,%rsi
  c7:   48 ba 00 00 00 00 00    movabs $0xffff880000000000,%rdx
  ce:   88 ff ff
  d1:   81 e6 f8 0f 00 00       and    $0xff8,%esi
  d7:   48 01 d6                add    %rdx,%rsi
  da:   48 ba 00 f0 ff ff ff    movabs $0x3ffffffff000,%rdx
  e1:   3f 00 00
  e4:   48 21 d0                and    %rdx,%rax
  e7:   48 01 f0                add    %rsi,%rax
  ea:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  eb:   c3                      retq
  ec:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking at disassembly of the `.o`, right?  Not the final linked binary?  The `0x0` address is just a placeholder that the linker will fill in.  (This is a memory-indirect call through a static/global function pointer).  `pud_offset` is getting inlined into your function.

Try `objdump -dr` or `-dR` to show the relocation entries in with the disassembly output.

Or better, look at `gcc -S` output to have symbolic names.  (`-fverbose-asm` is sometimes helpful).  Figure out the command line that `make` builds your file with, and modify it to use `-S -o-` instead of `-c`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I make **update** for start topic with disassemble details.
Does it mean the `call *0x0` means `call pv_mmu_ops`? What this `pv_mmu_ops` does?
Why the kernel use such complicated procedure to do dereferencing?
Sergey

Comment: @shs_sf: Note the `0xf8` offset from `pv_mmu_ops` that's part of the relocation.  Structs of function-pointers are very common in the kernel.  e.g. a filesystem registers itself for use by the rest of the kernel by calling a function that register a struct of function pointers with the part of the kernel that keeps track of all available filesystems.  FS ops on a mount of that FS type result in calls through those function pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Better look up source [code](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable.h?v=4.5#L670). As you can see, there is some [platform-specific](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable.h?v=4.5#L653) [address](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable.h?v=4.5#L665) magic.